# What is a vector in Python

Tags: python-2.7, vector

I was just looking at some Python and I came across something called a vector. What is this?

I am pretty sure it is something mathematical and complicated.

Comment: A vector is an element of a vector space. :) In numerical computing it's often just a single row or column of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector is similar to an Array. A vector holds multiple number values. In Python, you can do operations on vectors using things like dot product and cross product, in linear algebra. These operations are used to efficiently manipulate data when creating neural networks and 3d rendering.

For more of the math stuff you can look at this link:
[Math is fun: vectors](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: For linear algebra operations you would use the numpy library

Answer (score 0):

Well vectors originally are used to represent coordinates in a certain dimensional space(2d or 3d) or a line starting from the origin of a vector space,with both magnitude and direction.But in python vectors  are not a difficult concept or any of that kind,it is just a list of numbers which can be used for any operation usually in model training in machine learning,neural networks in short many things. They can be created in numpy as numpy as arrays since they are just arrays of numbers(scalars usually real numbers)